# Cookie in saml transaction

Tags: saml

From network trace in SP initiated saml, I am seeing the client browser send a cookie to the service provider url end in the Request, and then service provider returns back another new url (for resume saml transaction), along with three cookies- one being the same which was sent earlier by client, and two new cookies.

Why is the same cookie being returned to the client?

Comment: What is it named and what does it contain? What SP are you using?

Comment: Here is link to  https://ibb.co/g1rRvx  it shows the cookie in request is also same in response. The SP is saml 2.0 compliant app.

Answer (score 0):

It seem to be a cookie from netscaler that keep track of which server behind netscaler you are talking to.